# Selecting sorted data from a jTable in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a jTable that loads data from an excel file into the jTable unsorted. Each row of data has a unique ID number and I have a function that sorts the data by ID numerically. When a specific row in the table is clicked, that data ID is printed to the console. This works initially before the data is unsorted but after the data is sorted, the wrong ID is printed to the console. Here's what I have so far: The first function sorts the data by ID and the second function gets the (wrong) ID from the jTable and prints it to the console. How can I fix this so that the correct ID is selected?

```
private void sort(int columnIndex){
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(jTable1.getModel());
    jTable1.setRowSorter(sorter);
    List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>();
    sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(columnIndex, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
    sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
    sorter.sort();
}



private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        TableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        int index = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        String ID = dtm.getValueAt(index, 1).toString();
        System.out.println(ID);            
}
```

Example 1: The data is unsorted and I selected Job ID 8953528 so '8953528' is printed to the console like I initially planned.

[image]

Example 2: Now the data is sorted and I selected Job ID 8793343 but instead of printing that ID, '8953528' is printed again. Note: In both cases I selected data from the 3rd row.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click a row on a sorted `JTable`, `getSelectedRow()` gives you the 'visual' row index. What you want (in order to access the data) is the 'model' row index.

```
    index = sorter.convertRowIndexToModel(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to fix it

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(jTable1.getModel());
        int index = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        index = sorter.convertRowIndexToModel(index);
        System.out.println(jTable1.getValueAt(index, 0));  
}
```